# How to maximize a vector function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. $A$ is a known $m\times n$ matrix. $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to maximize the function $f(Ax)$.

How do I find the critical point of $x$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Since it's the same function, maximize f and then take a look on how to choose A to land on critical points

Comment: @Jan Why is it not well-defined? Can you specify?

Comment: Use the chain rule on $g(x)=Ax$ and $f(x)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you! Could you provide more details?

Comment: @NashTop Calculate the total dervative using the chain rule and when it's zero you've identified a critical point just like the single variable case. Taking the total derivative isn't particularly hard for a linear function like $Ax$ since the derivative is a linear operator. Try some small values of $m$ and $n$ with some specific matrices for $A$ and you'll see what's happening so you can generalize.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you very much! I will try it!